# Joining tables - a bit complicated

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Each week, my client runs radio spots and email campaigns through a third party marketing group to promote his product. He'd like to know how much he's making/spending each week, and to have the data broken down for him. The table data looks like this:

```
tablename: orders
+----------+--------------+---------------------+------------+
| order_id | order_amount | referral            | order_date |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1        | 16.00        | Radio: Jack Johnson | 2013-07-01 |
| 2        | 50.00        | Radio: Jack Johnson | 2013-07-02 |
| 3        | 16.00        | Radio: Jack Johnson | 2013-07-02 |
| 4        | 50.00        | Radio: Thabo Mbeki  | 2013-07-03 |
| 5        | 16.00        | Email: Renewal      | 2013-07-08 |
| 6        | 50.00        | Other               | 2013-07-08 |
| 7        | 16.00        | Email: Renewal      | 2013-07-08 |
| 8        | 50.00        | Radio: Thabo Mbeki  | 2013-07-09 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+

tablename: media
+----------+-------+-------+--------------+-------+------------+
| media_id | spots | cost  | name         | type  | date       |
+----------+-------+-------+--------------+-------+------------+
| 1        | 10    | 10000 | Jack Johnson | radio | 2013-07-01 |
| 2        | 5     | 5000  | Thabo Mbeki  | radio | 2013-07-01 |
| 3        | 10    | 10000 | Jack Johnson | radio | 2013-07-08 |
| 4        | 5     | 5000  | Thabo Mbeki  | radio | 2013-07-08 |
| 5        | 1     | 250   | Renewal      | email | 2013-07-08 |
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

I need to generate an HTML table like this:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| week       | name         | type  |spots | cost     | revenue | total orders | avg. per order |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| 2013-07-01 | Jack Johnson | radio | 10   | 10000    | 82.00   | 3            | 27.33          |
| 2013-07-01 | Thabo Mbeki  | radio | 5    | 5000     | 50.00   | 1            | 50.00          |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+
```

It gets complicated for me what I try to figure how to join the tables, and group them by the referral field from orders. Since orders.referral is not matched with media.name, I'm guessing there's a `WHERE referral LIKE %name` but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you have an option of fixing the tables (to break out referral into 2 columns?)

Comment: Yes, the data needs to be cleaned up. They have so many naming conventions, I'll never give them the accurate report they want to see. I'm implementing (with them) a proper naming scheme across all tables which should make a big difference in the query and in the results.

Comment: I meant more in terms of having the same separate name and type columns in orders table as they have in media table. The join would be MUCH easier

Comment: Yes, I understood, and that would make things easier. Using the solutions below, I was able to use CONCAT() to combine the 'type' and the 'name' to sort of recreate the 'referral'. But separating them into 2 fields in the orders table would eliminate the need for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore "Other", a better join WHERE clause would be

```
WHERE orders.order_date = media.date
 AND  LOWER(orders.referral)   = LOWER(media.type + ": " + media.name)
```

This is Sybase syntax, I apologize if you will need to tweak it a bit for MySQL

To deal with "Other", simply do an outer join to "media" table.

Something like (didn't check for correctness) will do a per-date report; you will need to massage it further to group by week if you wish to (that's not hard but I feel is outside the main scope of your question)

```
SELECT SUM(order.amount) AS revenue, COUNT(order.amount) as total_orders
      ,SUM(order.amount)/COUNT(order.amount) as average_order
      ,SUM(spots) spots, media.type, media.name, order_date
FROM   order
LEFT OUTER JOIN media 
ON        orders.order_date = media.date
     AND  LOWER(orders.referral)   = LOWER(media.type + ": " + media.name)
GROUP BY order.referral, order.date
-- May be add to group by:    , COALESCE(media.type,media.name,"Other")
```

Comment: Thank you for adding up the amounts and then COUNT(amount) which I couldn't think straight on. It's a great step. I also know now, that the data needs a clean up if they want good matches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT m.name, [other needed columns]
FROM media m JOIN orders o ON o.referral LIKE '%' + m.name +'%'
WHERE m.date between [date] and [date]
GROUP BY m.name, [other groupings]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you for putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

Great help here. This is the query I ended up using:

```
SELECT m.date, m.name, m.type, m.spots, m.cost, 
       SUM(o.order_amount) as revenue, 
       COUNT(o.order_amount) as orders,
       SUM(o.order_amount)/COUNT(o.order_amount) as average_order 
FROM   media m
JOIN   orders o
ON     LOWER(o.referral) = CONCAT(LOWER(m.type), ': ' ,LOWER(m.name))
WHERE  (DATE(o.order_date) BETWEEN '2013-06-24' AND '2013-06-30')
GROUP BY m.name, m.type
```